# R only specify optional parameters if specified

Tags: r

I have an R function with optional parameters like so:

```
myFunc <- function(
    requiredParam,
    optionalParam1 = optionalValue1,
    optionalParam2 = optionalValue2,
    ...
    optionalParamN = optionalValueN) {
    # implementation
}
```

I have another function which calls this function and has the necessary parameters stored in a dataframe:

```
  optionalParam1 optionalParam3 optionalParam10
1         "val1"         "val2"          "val3"
```

I only want to pass the optional parameters specified in the dataframe. For the others, I want it to use the default values. How can I accomplish this without typing up all permutations of optionalParameters existing/not existing?

Answer (score 2):

Call the function using `do.call` (not knowing what your data.frame is called I will just assume you have a list or something of the parameters called `myParams`):

```
do.call(myFunc, as.list(myParams))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also build your function call as a string by parsing your dataframe column names and using `paste`.

Then, use `eval(parse(text="your string"))`